# Owl Carousel v.1.3.3, cannot change slider speed

Tags: wordpress-theming, owl-carousel

I'm using a Wordpress theme that comes with Owl Carousel v.1.3.3 and the slider goes far too fast.  I've already tried all the tips I can find but nothing seems to have any effect on the speed whatsoever!  I attach my code here, the autoPlaySpeed and autoPlayTimeout are what I've just added from other answers here, but still no change to the speed.  Please help!

```
   $.fn.owlCarousel.options = {

    items : 5,
    itemsCustom : false,
    itemsDesktop : [1199, 4],
    itemsDesktopSmall : [979, 3],
    itemsTablet : [768, 2],
    itemsTabletSmall : false,
    itemsMobile : [479, 1],
    singleItem : false,
    itemsScaleUp : false,

    slideSpeed : 300,
    paginationSpeed : 500,
    rewindSpeed : 1000,

    autoPlay :true,
    autoPlaySpeed: 5000,
    autoPlayTimeout: 5000,
    stopOnHover : false,

    navigation : false,
    navigationText : ["prev", "next"],
    rewindNav : true,
    scrollPerPage : false,

    pagination : true,
    paginationNumbers : false,

    responsive : true,
    responsiveRefreshRate : 200,
    responsiveBaseWidth : window,

    baseClass : "owl-carousel",
    theme : "owl-theme",

    lazyLoad : false,
    lazyFollow : true,
    lazyEffect : "fade",

    autoHeight : false,

    jsonPath : false,
    jsonSuccess : false,

    dragBeforeAnimFinish : true,
    mouseDrag : true,
    touchDrag : true,

    addClassActive : false,
    transitionStyle : false,

    beforeUpdate : false,
    afterUpdate : false,
    beforeInit : false,
    afterInit : false,
    beforeMove : false,
    afterMove : false,
    afterAction : false,
    startDragging : false,
    afterLazyLoad: false
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the slide speed For Owl Carousel v.1.3.3, replace this
autoPlay :true,
with your slide speed
autoPlay :5000,

hope this help.